# Easy way to create multiple-dimension arrays in C++ with new operator

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator

I need to create a lot of small 2-dimension arrays in C++ code.
The problem is that it's a lot of work to create even a simple array:

```
new int* [2]{
            new int[2]{9, 9},
            new int[2]{25, 19}
    };
```

Is there any better way how to do that?
I wanted to avoid writing "new int[]..." every time.

Comment: Isn't it OK to use `std::vector` instead of arrays?

Comment: One of solutions may be creating a function that takes `std::vector` and returning arrays that represents the given vector.

Comment: Maybe you want `std::vector<std::array<int,2>>` or `std::array<std::array<int,2>,2>`

Comment: Can you allocate as a huge one dimensional array, then treat it as a two dimensional array?  This would keep all values together, instead of having an array of pointers.

Comment: Is it really necesary for you to assing the values at the moment you create them? Or is there a chance for you to get the values later? If you have to assing values at the moment of creation. Is there a pattern to the values?

Comment: This is done for CUDA programming and I didn't want to use STL.

And I also wanted to treat is as a array of arrays.

Comment: @Pablochaches actually, these matrices are used for UnitTesting, (these that I create are input, then do some operations on them and then validate it).

Comment: CUDA programming likes to have it's data in sequential, contiguous locations.  Processors don't like having to reload their data caches.  Processors like to fetch data from the outside world as few times as possible.  They to be in their private little world,executing instructions from a pipeline or cache and fetching data from a close internal cache.

Comment: That's a very verbose and inefficient way to create arrays, particularly if they have fixed dimensions. Why did you choose this complicated, dynamically allocating approach?

Comment: That was suggested by my lecturer, probably because these matrices may be very big (and as I understand, using array of arrays, we can contain more values than using single-array). Am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the dimensions are not decided at runtime, and all the inner arrays have the same dimensions, you do not need dynamic allocation here.

Just declare an array:

```
int myArray[2][2] = {
   {9, 9},
   {25, 19}
};
```

That's it!

Answer (score 3):

I recommend allocating as a single dimension array.  You can then treat the 1D array as a 2D array:

```
const unsigned int MAX_ROWS = 2U;
const unsigned int MAX_COLUMNS = 5U;
int example_array[MAX_ROWS * MAX_COLUMNS];
//  Get value at [row][column]:
unsigned int one_dim_index = (row * MAX_COLUMNS) + column;
int value = example_array[one_dim_index];
```

For small array sizes, this would be more efficient since the processor can fit the entire contiguous array in the data cache.  With your solution, an array of pointers, you have no idea where the sub-arrays are located and they may not be contiguous (thus requiring a refetch into the cache).

**Edit 1: Initializing**
You can initialize the array by making the rows and columns *pretty*:

```
int example_array[MAX_ROWS * MAX_COLUMNS] =
{
    /* row 0 */ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
    /* row 1 */ 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
};
```

Comment: I know this approach but for my case I probalby need to use int**.

Comment: CUDA programming likes to have its data in sequential, contiguous locations.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. 
Actually, I have two implementations, and the second one is working on array[ M * N ] implementation. But this is done for some college things and I had to use also approach with int**. That's why I wanted to know if there's a better way to handle this.

Comment: Arrays with fixed dimensions are already contiguous, so your complication with the index mapping was unnecessary. Just declare an `int example_array[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS]` (or flip the dimensions if you like)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use nested for loops to do the task

```cpp
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 2;

int **create_array() {

  int **array = new int*[ARRAY_SIZE];
  if (array == nullptr) { return nullptr; }

  for (int i=0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
    array[i] = new int[ARRAY_SIZE];
    if (array[i] == nullptr) { return nullptr; }
  }
  return array;
}
```

If you want to assing the values you can do it directly in here. But they should come from a function of i. If you want some really specific values it will need to be a manual job